How to count the number of independent components of a tensor?
Let's suppose that I have a four dimensional manifold $M$ and a tensor $\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$ defined on $M$. $\phi$ satisfies the conditions:
$$\phi^{[\alpha\beta][\mu\nu]}=\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}, ~~\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}=0,~~ \phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}=\phi^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}.$$
How can I know how many independent components the tensor $\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$ has? The square brackets $[~]$ denote antysimmetrization.
It is very easy to check that $\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$ has, initially, 256 components, however, I don't know how to count the independent components using the properties stated above. It is clear that an antisymmetric tensor $A^{[\mu\nu]}=A^{\mu\nu}$ has, in four dimensions, only 6 independent components. However, I don't know how to use this fact in the case in which $\phi^{[\alpha\beta][\mu\nu]}=\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$. Also, I don't know exactly what the condition $\phi^{[\alpha\beta][\mu\nu]}=\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$ means. Does it means that $\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}=-\phi^{\beta\alpha\mu\nu}$ and $\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}=-\phi^{\alpha\beta\nu\mu}$?
I have tried to do something analogous in lower dimensions, counting the number of independent components of, for example, $\phi^{\mu\nu}$, but it is difficult to find a general strategy to do the same in four dimensions.
The correct answer for the problem is that $\phi^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}$ has only 20 independent components, but I have no idea how to arrive to that result (killing 236 components).

So the best I can do for you is run my python (2) code that takes tensor products of irreducible representations and computes sums irreducible subspaces from first the Young diagram that represents the partition of the number in indices $4$ as $4, 3+1, 2+2, 1+1+1+1$, and then for each of those, finds the standard Young tableaux and fills them in LATIN indices (sorry, I should do unicode greek for 4-D, but I didn't), and then for those, it uses the remarkable Hook Length Formula to compute the dimension of those based on the dimension of the fundamental irrep (here: 4).
Sadly, my general code is for $\mathbb{R}^3$, for which it will write out the LaTex for tensor indices for each irrep (e.g. [i][j]$\rightarrow (T_{ij} + T_{ji})/\sqrt 2$), but I don't have it for $\mathbb{R}^4$ (maybe, when I get some time...)
In [70]: B = geo.schur_weyl.young.Diagram(1)
In [71]: for diagram in B^B^B^B:
...:     print '='*20

...:     print unicode(diagram)

...:     print "Dimension=", diagram.dimW(4)

...:     print "Number of tableaux:", diagram.dim()

...:     print "Tableux:"

...:     for table in diagram.standard_tableaux():

...:         print table

...:         print '-'*40

====================
☐☐☐☐
Dimension= 35
Number of tableaux: 1
Tableux:
[i][j][k][l]

====================
☐☐☐
☐
Dimension= 45
Number of tableaux: 3
Tableux:
[i][j][k]
[l]

[i][j][l]
[k]

[i][k][l]
[j]

====================
☐☐☐
☐
Dimension= 45
Number of tableaux: 3
Tableux:
[i][j][k]
[l]

[i][j][l]
[k]

[i][k][l]
[j]

====================
☐☐☐
☐
Dimension= 45
Number of tableaux: 3
Tableux:
[i][j][k]
[l]

[i][j][l]
[k]

[i][k][l]
[j]

====================
☐☐
☐☐
Dimension= 20
Number of tableaux: 2
Tableux:
[i][j]
[k][l]

[i][k]
[j][l]

====================
☐☐
☐☐
Dimension= 20
Number of tableaux: 2
Tableux:
[i][j]
[k][l]

[i][k]
[j][l]

====================
☐☐
☐
☐
Dimension= 15
Number of tableaux: 3
Tableux:
[i][j]
[k]
[l]

[i][k]
[j]
[l]

[i][l]
[j]
[k]

====================
☐☐
☐
☐
Dimension= 15
Number of tableaux: 3
Tableux:
[i][j]
[k]
[l]

[i][k]
[j]
[l]

[i][l]
[j]
[k]

====================
☐☐
☐
☐
Dimension= 15
Number of tableaux: 3
Tableux:
[i][j]
[k]
[l]

[i][k]
[j]
[l]

[i][l]
[j]
[k]

====================
☐
☐
☐
☐
Dimension= 1
Number of tableaux: 1
Tableux:
[i]
[j]
[k]
[l]

Anyway: that python spew contains all the symmetries of a rank-4 tensor in 4 dimensions.
